# probabilistic and deterministic techniques and mathematical methods that exist for sensor fusion so far

Tags: probability-theory, monte-carlo, kalman-filter, fuzzy-logic

I am not sure whether this is the right site on StackExchange to ask this question. I am relatively new in here at least as an active memeber. Nevertheless I thought mathematicians would know more methods that exist at least in theory than engineers. I am sorry if it is not the case.

I categorized for the very first chapters of my ongoing PhD thesis the sensor fusion techniques for autonomous vehicles into probabilistic techniques such as Kalman filters, Extended Kalman filters, Occupancy grids and Monte-Carlo methods and deterministic techniques such as fuzzy logic controllers, interval calculus and probability gerneration methods.

I did this based on a bibliography and readings I did before. Now I am going in depth for each of my listed methods.

Does anyone think that I forgot to mention or investigate an other important technique or mathematical approach with regard to this categorization?

Keywords for other techniques and methods would be very welcome ...

Thanks in advance for any hint or help!

Here is my categorization work so far:
[image]

Comment: Would you count normal [state observers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_observer), such as Luenberger observers, as non-probabilistic?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I think yes from what I understood now on high fly level. However I have to read more about them.